# Replit database.get returns null when used with a parameter but not when used with the value of the paramater?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api, replit

I have an express GET request I'm using for a login page, and the first step in the login process is making sure that the user exists, but the thing is, while this returns a value -

`users.get('Example Username').then((response)=>{console.log(response)})`

This does not -
`users.get(req.query.username).then((response)=>{console.log(response)}))`

Even though the fetch request was equivalent to `fetch('/checkUser?username="Example Username"')`